# Finding the common interior of $r=4(1+\sin\theta)$, $r=4(1-\sin\theta)$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I am not sure how to find the common area between the two functions. I am not sure how to determine the bounds of the integrals.

[image: This is the link to how I tried to solve it]

I tried setting the functions equal to each other

$4(1+\sin\theta)=4(1-\sin\theta)$ and got $\pi$ and $2\pi$ I am just not sure how to complete the rest.

Comment: The desired region is symmetrical: its area is four times the region limited to the first quadrant. Use the blue curve only and let $\theta$ range from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: Oh now I understand! Thank you so much

Comment: General advice -- be warned:  it is a good idea to know the values of $ \ \theta \ $ at which _each curve_ passes through the origin (they are not necessarily the same for each) when setting up this type of polar-area problem.  Setting the curve functions equal to one another _does not_ give you that information because the equation becomes $ \ 0 \ = \ 0 \ $ at the origin; equating curve functions only gives reliable information for intersections _other than_ the origin.